# What will happen to existing builds if I revoked distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate

I want to create the new distribution certificate for my new app and my existing certificate limit is over for the distribution certificate. So I have revoked the existing distribution certificate but before that, I have done my research and I conclude that it will not affect my existing builds but unfortunately my builds stop working.

Can anyone help me with this scenario? After revoking, why my existing builds are stopped working?

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoking of the certificate will **not affect** the **builds** that are **published** and **installed** on the devices

But **revoking** of certificates will definitely **disable** your **in-house** app because the device will regularly validate with apple server for the certificates, that the builds are signed with the certificate are valid or not.

So your in-house build will be invalid once you revoked the certificate but your app store build will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Revoking a distribution certificate has no effect on existing distributions, such as the apps already in the App Store.

But it does affect anything you do from now on.

Comment: Got it @matt, thanks a lot. just my inhouse build are getting invalid after the revoking of the certificate.